# jquery $('body').on('click') always needs .off('click') to avoid multiple event firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I have a page where I list my crew members (show_crew.php). The page runs on with infinite scrolling plugin, like Google Images does. At first, I show 10 entries. If the user reaches the bottom of show_crew.php, a new 'show_crew.php' is appended to the old one, showing the next 10 entries.

I heave some Jquery functions embedded in show_crew.php, where I bind events via

```
$('body').on('click', 'myButton[rel=<? echo $user['id'] ?>]', function() {
    console.log('foo');
})​
```

Now, as show_crew.php is appended multiple times, the event is also bound to the same button multiple times. I can fix this problem via `$('body').off('click', 'myButton')` EACH TIME.

This looks ugly. Is there a more elegant way?

thanks, 
matt

Comment: @Smamatti: the two are equal in that OP's code doesn't have to be re-bound when new elements are added to the DOM. That type of bindings were introduced to solve the exact problem that OP is creating here, by binding multiple times when once would suffice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You only need to bind the delegated events once. Don't rebind every time the content is loaded.

Using the format of `$('body').on('click', '...selector...', function () {...})` will delegate the event handler to the `<body>` element. What this means is that the body will catch all `click` events and check whether they occurred on an element that matches `...selector...`. If it did, it'll trigger the event handler *as if it were triggered on the matched element*.

Once you've added the delegate listener, there's no need to worry about rebinding, as the children of `<body>` can change, and the delegate will persist for new elements. This is a **very good thing™**.

Comment: I know, but I am in a sql loop, where I have to fetch the user IDs every time.

Comment: @MatthiasLang: But you don't have to bind the listener every time.

Comment: @MatthiasLang Give all of the buttons a similar class then bind using that class rather than binding an event for each user.

Comment: But how do I get the user's specific button ids, then? eg button[rel=<? echo $user['id'] ?>]

Comment: @MatthiasLang, there's no need to care what the `[id]`s are. Use classes, and if you need context within the event handler, `this` is a reference to the matched element. `$(this).attr('id')` will get you the `[id]` attribute of the matched element within the handler if you really need it.